# How should I consider the word "scenery"

Tags: countability

I think "scenery" is uncountable and the dictionary says it is.

Nevertheless the sentence "What a beautiful scenery!" sounds correct to me.

Should I rather say: "What some beautiful scenery!"

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

"According to English grammar, it must be used without article because 'scenery' is an uncountable noun."

> "What some beautiful scenery!"

No.

> "What a beautiful scenery!"

Only slightly incorrect.

> "What beautiful scenery!"

Yes!

> "What a beautiful scene!"

Also fine.

Answer (score -1):

Both are grammatically correct, but I'd say ***what beautiful scenery***, without *some*, is the one that serves the meaning you're trying to express better.

*some* there quantifies the noun, and that would make it sound that being beautiful may not be the source of the speaker's excitement, but is rather mentioned as a defining quality, and makes unclear then the wow factor to that beautiful scenery.